# Querying the data from sql table using non key column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

let's say I have a table in my DB called `songs`. The columns are `id, song_title, author`.

So, instead of querying like this,

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = 23
```

Is it OK (no problem at all) to query like this..?

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_title = 'Rain Over Me'
```

Will there be any side effects ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have an index on song_title, the query will scan the clustered index. Assuming the id is the primary key, that will then just be an index seek.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get any of ur words. I'm just a newbie here.. So, could u please be little bit human readable ?

Comment: No 'side effects'.  People run queries like this all the time.

Comment: @dbbri Thanks! So, no problem with spaces right ?

Comment: No, SQL looks at them like any other character.

Comment: Thanks! will do like that :)

Comment: You need to change your double quotes to single quotes...

Comment: Mentioned earlier, but ... Indexes on your data allow for speed. This is important if you have many rows in the table. The index will allow the query to be efficient and go directly to the right row. 
So assuming the id is indexed in the table, this means that searching it by that id is ultra fast. Assuming the title is not indexed, searching by title means that the database will have to retrieve every single row and check if the title matches, and than it'll return all lines that matched.
So a side effect: yes, in all likelihood there's a big impact on speed (or load on the database server).

Comment: @swa66 Thanks! That makes sense. I'm building an auto complete search box. That's why I need this. :) I need to try this first to see the god or bad results :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first query will be some sort of search...
You might also want to read up on the like operator.

The way you have your query written at the moment, the text will have to match the title exactly before it will be returned. If you intended this to be a search, your users will find something like this easier to use.

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_title LIKE '%Rain%'
```

This will return all songs where 'Rain' is in the title.

As for the side effects...

Assuming there's no index on song_title, the query won[t be using an index to search on. That said, you can create more than one index per table, and an index doesn't have to be on the primary key of the table. An index can also consist of multiple columns.

I'm guessing you'll be fine without an index anyway ;-)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I'm building an auto complete searchbox, So, when the user types something, it finds matching texts using `jQuery-ui` auto-complete. So, after user click the correct match, that text will be used to go to that result. Anyway, I see that using `LIKE` will be better than `WHERE` though.

Comment: Just to ask, without index it also means it will scan entire table to match conditions right ?